# Need help identifying an SMD component - top marking PJt

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, phototransistor

I'm wondering if anyone can help identify this component, with top marking PJt.

[image: Photo of PCB showing unknown component]

It's a 6-pin package and it's connected to a phototransistor. The collector is connected to pin 6 and the emitter is connected to pin 5 via a 10 kΩ resistor. Pin 1 is gnd, pin 3 goes through a 330 Ω resistor into pin 2 then through a 2.6 kΩ to gnd. Pin 6 goes to a 10 kΩ resistor. Pin 5 goes through the diode to gnd.

I'm thinking it's a comparator to give a high/low output from the phototransistor, but I can't find any comparators with a similar pinout.

Comment: Can you get some accurate dimensions? It looks like an SOT363 but it could be different. Also use the circuit tool and draw a schematic (edit the question). Also which pins are VCC and GND?

Comment: I got nothing on this being an amp, but lots of diodes can you check the pins with a diode meter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part appears to be a BC846BPN: https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BC846BPN.pdf  It is a NPN/PNP transistor pair. Page 2 shows part marking is 'PJ' with 't' indicating made in Malaysia.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The markings with t, p and W always represents the Nexperia.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and provide a source/link to the image

Comment: Ganesh Thiva - Hi, As well as the [required](/help/referencing) reference link for the image being missing, as kindly mentioned in the above comment, your answer seems to be wrong. The image you included says that a 2N7002BK will be marked "LN-" or "LNp" or "LNt" or "LNW" i.e. "LN {something}". But the device in the question is marked "PJt". How do you explain that the device in the original question has a marking that is not shown in your answer? Why do you believe that your answer is correct? Thanks.